# Keeping local changes in a git repo

Tags: git

Say I have a file in a git repo:

```
#file.py

setting1 = default1
setting2 = default2

<some code>
```

Now I want to make some local changes that don't get pushed back into the repo

```
#file.py - local change

setting1 = mysetting1
setting2 = mysetting2

<some code>
```

Say sometime in the future the upstream repo is updated, and I want to pull down their changes without messing up my local settings. I.E a git command I could run that would update the file so that it would be

```
#file.py - updated copy

setting1 = mysetting1
setting2 = mysetting2

<new code>
```

Is there some way to do this, either with branches or some other git feature where I don't have to put local settings in a separate file?

I've seen several other questions like this, but they focus on excluding a whole file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `git stash`. It is also a "whole file" method, but you might find it is flexible enough.

Otherwise, using `git gui` and a lot of rebasing (`git rebase --interactive`) or cherry-picking (`git cherry-pick`) or just a side branch should help.

Comment: Thanks. Actually stashing **does** do merging of files so that has the same affect on the file. I find having a local branch and rebasing to to be the most reliable as it seems like it would be easy to lose a stash and therefore all my changes.

Comment: Oh, I never meant to imply it does not merge. I just wanted to say you can't save a part of the changes (discarding the rest) in the file with one command.

Comment: The only problem with all of these methods is if git merge always has a conflict if a line is added directly below an edited one. For example if I have code like above, and I were to add "setting3 = default" below setting2 in the origin branch, the rebase (or every other method) would fail with a conflict, but if I add a line between the two, it does the rebase or whatever fine. Any idea why?

Comment: The merge algorithm takes the context of the changes into account. It just so happens that sometimes it has enough context information to figure the result safely. Luckily, it usually does not and aborts the textual merge operation, saving you from troubles with mismerged text. It still happens sometimes, so the algorithm is usually switched off for release integrations (`git merge -s resolve`).

Comment: what does the resolve algorithm do? (Differently than the default merge)?

Comment: @korylprince: It is best described in `git merge` man page, section **MERGE STRATEGIES**. The default "merge strategy" is the "recursive", the second in the list.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is probably changing connection strings and such. It is something that is local to your environment. The proper way to handle this is through smudge/clean scripts. Take a look at the ["Git Attributes" chapter in the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) (freely available).

Comment: Whether this turns out to be what he needs or not, thank you for linking to it, pretty clever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think I need anything this powerful, but it may become useful later.